# Unzip Folder in Android

Tags: android, unzip

I try to make an app that show 100 pictures.
I want to zip folder of photos and then put it on my project.
now i need to understand How can copy a zip folder to internal storage,And then unzip it in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include your .zip file on Assets folder of apk, and them on code, copy the .zip to internal storage and unzipping using a [ZipInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

First copy de .zip file to internal storage, and after unzip a file:

```
    protected void copyFromAssetsToInternalStorage(String filename){
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream input = assetManager.open(filename);
            OutputStream output = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

             copyFile(input, output);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void unZipFile(String filename){
        try {
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(openFileInput(filename));
            ZipEntry zipEntry;

            while((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null){
                FileOutputStream zipOutputStream = openFileOutput(zipEntry.getName(), MODE_PRIVATE);

                int length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                while((length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                zipOutputStream.close();
                zipInputStream.closeEntry();
            }
            zipInputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have this error.what should i do?java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File filename/ contains a path separator  @Joseph

Comment: Your asset zip file is on root of Assets folder or inside of another folder?

Comment: @Joseph  how can i unzip to special folder with this code ? for example i want to extract files into chach directory : getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().toString()

Comment: @mahdi let me see if I understand, do you want unzip all content of .zip file to one folder on getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()?